# Getting following error "Value does not fall within the expected range" while deploying the SSRS report to Sharepoint 2013 site

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using Sharepoint 2013 Server for deploying the SSRS reports.

I have created the SSRS report using SQL Server data tool and when I tried to deploy that report into Sharepoint site I am getting the following error

```
    "rsSharePointError : Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error.
 ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.SharePointException: Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range."
```

I have gone through many blogs and tried to change "Resource Throttling"  to the maximum level. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: @abarisone Thanks for your reply..


My problem got solved by adding a list in sharepoint server.
I have given the URL like (www.reportserver\sites\bi\library) in SSRS.

Comment: This can probably be closed as "no MCVE" or "not possible to reproduce".