# SSRS - Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, ssrs-2012

I have created a report in Visual Studio, deployed this using SSDT to a remote desktop where our SSRS service is running. This has deployed without any errors and I can see my data source and report on remote desktop.

However when I go to test the connection on the data source I get the following error: 'Value does not fall within the expected range'

[image]

I am using an OLE DB connection but am completely stumped as to why this is an issue. I have looked through previous questions and see the majority of the questions revolve around share point which i'm not using.

Any help much appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Is this error in SSDTBI or in Report Manager? If Report Manager, then is there any additional information in the Logs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms157403.aspx)? Do you have Postgre OLEDB driver installed on the Report Server?

Comment: Are you trying to integrate this with CRM?  If so, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645406/getting-following-error-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-while) might help.